# On a property of random variables and Borel sets

Tags: probability, random-variables, borel-sets

> **Proposition:** Let $A$ be a Borel set of $\mathbb{R}$. We wish to show that for any two random variables, $X,Y:\Omega\to \mathbb{R}$, then we have the following inequality:
>   $$ |\operatorname{P}(X\in A)-\operatorname{P}(Y\in A)|\leq \operatorname{P}(X\neq Y)$$

Here's where I'm at right now:

I tried showing it for an open interval $(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)$ but I could not find the property to use. I was trying to start with $\operatorname{P}(X\neq Y)$ and using the fact that if $X\neq Y$, we have $|X-Y|>0$. If you have any hints, I would be grateful.

---

*Edit:* Thanks for the answers using expected value and caracteristic functions. It's a pretty elegant way to do things. Unfortunatly, I would prefer a solution without using theses methods since the book I'm reading did not introduce the expected value of a random variable yet.

Comment: I edited my answer to give an alternate proof of the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: The left side is
\begin{align*}
  |P(X \in A) - P(Y \in A)| &= \left|E \left[1_{X \in A} - 1_{Y \in A} \right] \right| \\
& \leq E \left|1_{X \in A} - 1_{Y \in A}\right| \\
& = E \left[1_{X \in A, Y \not \in A} + 1_{X \not \in A, Y \in A} \right]
\end{align*}

EDIT, in response to edited original post: We can still play this game without resorting to expectations. Note that
$$\{X \in A\} = \{X \in A, Y \not \in A\} \cup \{X \in A, Y \in A\}$$
and
$$\{Y \in A\} = \{X \not \in A, Y \in A\} \cup \{X \in A, Y \in A\}$$
and that these are disjoint unions. Hence,
\begin{align*} \left| P(X \in A) - P(Y \in A) \right| &= \left|P(X \in A, Y \not \in A) - P(X \not \in A, Y \in A) \right| \\
&\leq P(X \in A, Y \not \in A) + P(X \not \in A, Y \in A).
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
&|\mathsf{E}[1\{X\in A\}-1\{Y\in A\}]|=|\mathsf{E}[(1\{X\in A\}-1\{Y\in A\})1\{X\ne Y\}]| \\[8pt]
&\qquad\le\mathsf{E}[|1\{X\in A\}-1\{Y\in A\}|1\{X\ne Y\}]\le \mathsf{E}1\{X\ne Y\}.
\end{align}

Comment: When you put $\le$ or $=$ immediately before an alignment tab, instead of manually adding space after it, just put a pair of {curly braces}, i.e. {}, after it. That will result in the standard amount of space between the binary operation symbol and the thing that follows it. I edited this answer accordingly.